# iframe content is not displaying in jquery dialoge in IE. It shows only a blank dialog

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe

```
$(function(){      
var options = {
      autoOpen: false,
      modal: true,
      show: 'slide',
      resizable: false,       
      width: 800,       
      height: 700       

 };       
     $('#dialog').append(iframe).appendTo("body").dialog(options);          
            // Dialog Link
            $('#dialog_click').click("callback",function(){         
                $('#dialog').dialog('open');                    
                return false;
            });
  });
```

This is my jQuery part and it is working properly in all other browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
     $(function(){      
        var options = {
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,           
        resizable: false,       
        width: 800,       
        height: 700       

             };       
 $('#dialog').append(iframe).appendTo("body").dialog(options);          
        // Dialog Link
        $('#dialog_click').click("callback",function(){         
            $('#dialog').dialog('open');                    
            return false;
        });
 });
```

Comment: thanks, It is working but having some issues in other browsers. and I trying to fix it